# Why can't you cancel both xs with 2x/3x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, indeterminate-forms

Consider that -

1. $x^3/x^2 = x $ as the exponent of the denominator is one higher than that of the numerator.
2. $x^2/x^2 = 1$

With $3x/2x$ it is not possible to cancel both $x$.

It seems like $3x/2x$ could be shown as $3x^1/2x^1$ meaning the $x$ should cancel like with $x^2/x^2 = 1$ leaving $3*1/2*1$

Please could someone explain to me the missing link as I cannot understand why this is not the case?

this is the fraction it came from:

$3x-x^2/2x+4$ I was told it can not be simplified further but I thought that the $3x /2x$ part could be turned to $3/2$ as the $x$ would cancel.

Comment: It is possible to cancel both $x$, as long as $x\neq 0$. That is, $\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}$ for $x\neq 0$. (for $x=0$ this expression doesn't make sense)

Comment: In particular, any expression containing $x$ in both the numerator and denominator gives us $\frac{0}{0}$ if blindly evaluated at $0$. This expression is meaningless and is one example of an [inderminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), so-called because they cannot be ascribed any value (inderminate value). To handle such cases, the [limiting value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) of the function at the point(s) where the inderminate form is encountered is useful.

Comment: Who told you this, and exactly what were you and they doing at the time? If it was something you read in a book, what came just before it? It would be strange if they told you you could cancel $x^2/x^2$ and *not* $3x/2x$ in the exact same circumstances, because both cancellations have similar limitations.

Comment: Is the expression in question wrongly reproduced at some point in the communication chain so that it is originally not $3x/2x$ but $3^x/2^x$? Then it makes sense that you can not cancel $x$. Sometimes like in $\sin(3x)/\sin(2x)$ you can cancel $\sin$ and $x$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linear algebra. Tags edited.

Comment: Did you mean $(3x-x^2)/(2x+4)$? Without parentheses you would just cancel $x^2/2x=1/2$ and leave the other terms alone...

Answer (score 5):

In such expressions

$$\frac{x^m}{x^n}$$

we can always cancel out terms without change its value but under the condition that $x\neq 0$, indeed

- $\frac{x}{x}=1$ for all $x\neq 0$

but

- $\frac{0}{0}$ is not defined.

Comment: So is it correct to say that it is because I don't know what $x$ is (and it could be 0) that I can not perform this calculation?

Comment: For the existence of the ratio we need $x\neq0$.

Comment: That is we can say: $ac/bx=a/b$ for $x\neq 0$ (and $b\neq0$).

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to check the denominator is not 0.

If the denominator is 0, we cannot define it.

If denominator is not 0, we can do reduction.

Answer (score 0):

> With $3x/2x$ it is not possible to cancel both $x.$

Why not? It's impossible only if $x=0.$ Provided $x$ is nonzero, you can simplify further.

As for $$3x-x^2/2x+4,$$ you may very well simplify further since this expression has no definite value whenever $x=0$ anyway. So we may assume (implicitly -- which is what's almost always done) without losing anything significant that $x\ne 0,$ and then simplify the middle term to become $-x/2.$